# When I double click Mainwindow.xib file the Interface Builder does not open in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

when I double click Mainwindow.xib file the Interface Builder does not open. I did some research but I could not solve it, I encounter with the same question on many websites but there is no solution.

I do not know the application type is important or not, I mean I have created iPhone Window-Based, iPhone Navigation-Based but the Interface Builder did not open.

Another thing is I use MonoTouch trial version, I do not know if it might be the reason for this. What can I do to solve it? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Try this: navigate the project directory, find your xib, right click on xib file and choose open with IB. Maybe it could fix your problem....

Comment: There is also a checkbox to "open always" with IB.  This is similar to associating file extensions in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that interface builder (xib) was not installed. I fixed this by reinstalling everything
as indicated on this page: http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation

But when I installed the Iphone SDK, I selected all components including the Mac API option.

Hope this helps:)

Benn